# No boot loader found - dual booting Windows 8 with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have been trying in vain to dual boot my computer with Windows 8 Pro (pre-installed) and Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I have been able to successfully install Ubuntu 14.04, but the option to start Ubuntu does not appear on startup. This is after having taken all steps as mentioned in [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported). I even tried the boot repair option and ended up with [this error log.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7461359/)

My questions are:

1. How do I solve for `No boot loaders found in /dev/...`?
2. Are there any other recommendations that will help me solve this?

Other points that may be important:

- Booting into Ubuntu from a live USB shows all Ubuntu partitions on the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading Super Grub from [www.supergrubdisk.org](http://www.supergrubdisk.org). Create a super grub boot usb. It should sort you out.

richory